# Duvida de ajax para criar uma página JS

Tags: ajax

Como eu faço para criar uma página javascript que contenha um botão que, quando eu clicar, ele acesse, via ajax, o conteúdo de um arquivo txt que está salvo na mesma pasta que a página em questão, e também exiba os seus dado dentro de um div com o id = "dados".

Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Portguês, talvez queira fazer uma **Tour**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou Dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e verificar como efetuar uma boa pergunta para que essa seja respondida. Deve postar o que você já tentou e também o código que está utilizando. Dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
   url: 'arquivo.txt',
   success: function(data){
    $('#app').append(data)
   }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
```

Assim, lembrando que se executar não ira funcionar, pois não possui o arquivo no diretorio atual